# Android - No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android

I tried below code to start downloading an mp3 file in android, it was right until this morning, now it throws this exeption `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= http://snd.tebyan.net/1388/03/Baz Amadam55055.mp3  }`both in emulator and real device, I did not change the code, what happened? what is wrong?

```
String url = " http://snd.tebyan.net/1388/03/Baz Amadam55055.mp3";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the space before `http` in your string:

```
String url = "http://snd.tebyan.net/1388/03/Baz Amadam55055.mp3";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

As Hariharan and Artoo pointed out, there are several bugs in the piece of code

There is a space in string `url`. Change it to 
`String url = "http://snd.tebyan.net/1388/03/Baz Amadam55055.mp3";`.

Moreover, you can't pass a `String` to start an intent. Convert it to a `Uri` object and then pass it to the `Intent` constructor. That is probably the line you accidentally deleted. Add the line `Uri uri = Uri.parse(url)` to your code. The final solution is something like:

```
String url = "http://snd.tebyan.net/1388/03/Baz Amadam55055.mp3";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

One last point is that the particular Url requires your emulator/device to contain an SD card. Go through your emulator's details and check if SD card is ticked and has a reasonable size in MB.

Answer (score 1):

```
String url = " http://snd.tebyan.net/1388/03/Baz Amadam55055.mp3";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
```

Here you're using two different names: **uri != url**...

And, as Hariharan said, there's an extra space in the uri (here called "url") definition.